# Enumerating Connections to WiFi

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, sharing

I am hosting WiFi from my ethernet-connected Windows machine. Is there any way for me to check how many devices are connected?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of free utilities to enumerate connected WiFi devices, such as Nirsoft's [Wireless Network Watcher](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html) and [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/wireless-network-watcher/). You can also [use the router's web interface to view connections](https://www.howtogeek.com/204057/how-to-see-who%E2%80%99s-connected-to-your-wi-fi-network/), or the (paid) professional version of Glasswire, which also displays network traffic.

The image below shows the interface for Wireless Network Watcher. Note that *MAC Address*, *Device Name* and *User Text* can be falsified, but if you know the parties using your WiFi, you can verify this information when each connects.

As with any software, check before using it that is does not contain malware with *pestudio* or *[VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload)*.

[image: Wireless Network Watcher interface]

Comment: As a highly valued member of Super User, please review [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  In particular, a brief overview of the specific features in the software that the OP is interested in would be a great addition to your answer.